# In frame, how to find username textbox's xpath with webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to sign in to http://www.timesjobs.com/. Upon signing in a pop-up appears (it is the css lightbox). Cannot find the exact xpath for the username on this sign-in box. I iterated over each and every frame and tried to use firefox generated xpath for username textbox. I got exception as:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//html/body//input[@name='j_username']"}.
```

Tried below code but no luck:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.timesjobs.com");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000L);
    List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    System.out.println("Total Frames: " + frames.size());
    int k =0;
    while(k<=frames.size()){

        try{driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            driver.switchTo().frame(k);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body//input[@name='j_username']"));
            we1.sendKeys("xyzusername@xyzcompany.com");
        System.out.println("in try BLOCK:"+k);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("in catch: "+k);
        }finally{
            k++;}
    }
    System.out.println("end of the program");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `input[@name='j_username']` is in iframe?

Comment: @olyv , yes... Anyways thanks. Got the answer below. There were 2 frames to reach to my inputbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. It works.

Your username Field is contained within GB_Frame which is contained under GB_Frame1. So we have to switch to GB_Frame1 and then to GB_Frame. Username field has a `name`, so better use it over `xpath`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.timesjobs.com");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.switchTo().frame("GB_frame1");
    driver.switchTo().frame("GB_frame");

    WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
    we1.sendKeys("xyzusername@xyzcompany.com");
}
```

I dont understand what difficulty you had in identifying the frames. It was pretty clear from the page source. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't find the frames with firebug or page source. Able to get your point when I **Inspected** in the firefox. Can you suggest any better-ways to find pagesource to avoid these problems?

Comment: Try using chrome. It has an inbuilt developer tools that helps in capturing xpath and testing them. You can change the focus to a particular frame if you want.